# Ingress controller not picking changes to new/existing Ingress resources

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway

Im usings AKS AGIC

Describe the bug
The deployed ingress control does not pick existing or newly created Ingress resources. The Ingress resources are properly annotated. On killing controller pod, the newly spawned pod is able to detect existing Ingress and update the Application Gateway accordingly. But after the initial sync up with Application Gateway, the pod will stop updating/listening for the Ingress existing/new resources.

I used port-foward and the resource is updated but when i use the ingress path the content isnt updated

I tried to see logs ingress logs and the service pod but everything is fine. the ingress logs are similar to the present in attached image

[image]

Comment: Similar thread-
https://github.com/Azure/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/issues/716

Comment: One possible cause is that AGIC pod is not running or healthy. You can verify this by running  `kubectl get pods -n kube-system`  and check the status of the AGIC pod. Another cause is that Ingress resources are not properly annotated with  `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway`. You can verify this by `kubectl describe ingress <ingress-name>`  and checking the annotations . If the AGIC pod is running and the Ingress resources are properly annotated, you can try checking logs for AGIC pod to see if any errors or issues `kubectl logs <agic-pod-name> -n kube-system`

Answer (score 1):

The problem was been caused because of the Application Gateway Path Based Rules created by my ingress. The rules were conflicting with each other. I had a path rule with /agendamento* and another /agendamentodigital*. Because of the position of the "*" nothing was being routed to /agendamentodigital*, because the traffic was routed for /agendamento* rule. /agendamento* =  /agendamento(ignore everything that comes after the word agendamento).

What i did to resolve the issue was puth a "/" after the word agendamento in my ingress config file. Before /agendamento. After /agendamento/

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are experiencing with the AGIC not picking up changes to new or existing Ingress resources may be due to a problem with the AGIC pod. You mentioned that killing the controller pod and spawning a new one allows it to detect existing Ingress resources and update the Application Gateway accordingly. This suggests that there may be an issue with the AGIC pod itself.

Your controller logs don't help much to troubleshoot this further, it just indicates, the logs indicate that the AGIC started up, is configured to watch for Ingress resources across all namespaces in the AKS cluster, has successfully authenticated using MSI, has synced its internal cache with the current state of the cluster, and has applied a configuration update to the Azure Application Gateway.

If you want to troubleshoot this, this please check for the
`kubectl get pods -n kube-system`  and check the status of the AGIC pod. Cross verify if the Ingress resources are not annotated with  `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway`. You can verify this by  `kubectl describe ingress <ingress-name>`  and checking the annotations.

Below is an example to setup AGIC on AKS cluster with an existing application gateway.
If you already have an AKS cluster, skip it. if not create a cluster as below-

```
az aks create -n <ClusterName> -g <ResourceGroup> --network-plugin azure --enable-managed-identity --generate-ssh-keys
```

deploy a new application gateway, change the names of myResourceGroup , myPublicIp, myVnet, mySubnet, myApplicationGateway with your choice of names

```
 az network public-ip create -n myPublicIp -g myResourceGroup --allocation-method Static --sku Standard
```

[image]

```
az network vnet create -n myVnet -g myResourceGroup --address-prefix 10.0.0.0/16 --subnet-name mySubnet --subnet-prefix 10.0.0.0/24
```

[image]

```
az network application-gateway create -n myApplicationGateway -g myResourceGroup --sku Standard_v2 --public-ip-address myPublicIp --vnet-name myVnet --subnet mySubnet --priority 100
```

[image]

Now enable the AGIC add-on in the AKS cluster

```
appgwId=$(az network application-gateway show -n myApplicationGateway -g myResourceGroup -o tsv --query "id") 
az aks enable-addons -n myCluster -g myResourceGroup -a ingress-appgw --appgw-id $appgwId
```

[image]

If you’d like to use Azure portal to enable AGIC add-on, go to [(https://aka.ms/azure/portal/aks/agic)](https://aka.ms/azure/portal/aks/agic) and navigate to your AKS cluster. From there, go to the Networking tab under your AKS cluster. You’ll see an application gateway ingress controller section, with option to enable/disable the ingress controller add-on using the Azure portal.
[image]

Since I’ve deployed the AKS cluster in its own virtual network and the Application gateway in another virtual network, I’ll have to peer the two virtual networks together in order for traffic to flow from the Application gateway to the pods in the cluster.

```
nodeResourceGroup=$(az aks show -n myCluster -g myResourceGroup -o tsv --query "nodeResourceGroup")
aksVnetName=$(az network vnet list -g $nodeResourceGroup -o tsv --query "[0].name")

aksVnetId=$(az network vnet show -n $aksVnetName -g $nodeResourceGroup -o tsv --query "id")
az network vnet peering create -n AppGWtoAKSVnetPeering -g myResourceGroup --vnet-name myVnet --remote-vnet $aksVnetId --allow-vnet-access

appGWVnetId=$(az network vnet show -n myVnet -g myResourceGroup -o tsv --query "id")
az network vnet peering create -n AKStoAppGWVnetPeering -g $nodeResourceGroup --vnet-name $aksVnetName --remote-vnet $appGWVnetId --allow-vnet-access
```

[image]

Done. Now deploying a sample application to the AKS cluster that will use the AGIC add-on for Ingress and connect the application gateway to the AKS cluster.

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/master/docs/examples/aspnetapp.yaml

kubectl get ingress
```

[image]
[image]

Reference Documents:

- [AGIC on AKS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/tutorial-ingress-controller-add-on-existing)
- [Common Questions and troubleshooting for AGIC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ingress-controller-troubleshoot#inspect-kubernetes-installation)
- [Similar Thread](https://github.com/Azure/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/issues/716)